# Jquery ScrollTo and IE8 Issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scrollto

so basically I have a little slideshow on this site www.dudnykexchange.com which animates up and down and runs a slide show in the first of the ScrollTo elements. It works fine in every browser but IE when it throws the an error saying Object doesnt support this property or method. the specific line it points to is the ScrollTo call. I know it's not the slideshow breaking it because I have the exact same code working elsewhere.

here's a snippet of what's breaking...

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#show_hold').scrollTo('#exc_slide', 0 );
```

Inturn this error is breaking the slideshow and making a whole big mess. Is there a fix or should a work around be implemented and does anyone know how to go about a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a shot here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6452 maybe that's what you're looking for.